# use of out-of-scope declaration

Tags: c, gcc, clang

Code:

```
void foo() {
    extern int a;
    extern void b(int);
}

void bar() {
    b(9); // ok, warning: use of out-of-scope declaration of 'b'
    a=9; // error: use of undeclared identifier 'a'
}
```

Why the compiler doesn't just give a warning like `use of out-of-scope declaration of 'a'`?

Comment: @M.M then where would the declarations be?

Comment: @M.M: A test at godbolt.com gives different messages depending on whether `b` is declared in `foo` or not. I suspect the particular cause of the message OP sees is that a function identifier always refers to the same function in a module, so the `b` in `bar` **must** refer to the same `b` as in `foo`, but its declaration is out of scope, whereas `a` could refer to a different object.

Comment: @EricPostpischil you're right - I thought the declaration of `b` in `foo` didn't matter if it wasn't actually called, since the declaration went out of scope,  but in fact it does matter

Answer (score 5):

This is because of the vestigial feature of *implicit declaration* of functions.  If you had just

```
void bar()
{
    b(9);    
}
```

that would actually be 100% valid *pre-standard* C (well, except that `void` didn't exist back then, but that's not important right now) equivalent to writing

```
void bar()
{
    extern int b();
    b(9);    
}
```

(Remember that an empty parameter list in a function declaration does *not* mean that the function takes zero arguments.  It means the function takes an *unspecified number* of arguments.)

Now, when you have

```
void foo()
{
    extern void b(int);
}

void bar()
{
    b(9);
}
```

the implicit declaration means it's like you wrote

```
void foo()
{
    extern void b(int);
}

void bar()
{
    extern int b();
    b(9);
}
```

The two declarations of the external symbol `b` are not compatible.  If they were both visible in the scope of `bar`, this would be a constraint violation ("X is a constraint violation" is the closest the C standard ever comes to saying "a program that does X is invalid and the compiler must reject it").  But they're not, so instead, the program's meaning is undefined.  clang seems to have decided to apply the declaration from the `foo` scope but also warn you about it, which seems fair to me.  gcc does treat it as an error:

```
test.c:6:5: error: incompatible implicit declaration of function ‘b’
     b(9);
     ^
test.c:2:17: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘b’ was here
     extern void b(int);
                 ^
```

("previous implicit declaration" is not quite right, but that is also not important right now.)

You can probably see how this sort of thing could lead to hard-to-find bugs, which is why modern best practice is to declare stuff with external linkage *only* at file scope, and to declare all functions with full prototypes.

Only functions are ever implicitly declared, which is why `a` gave a hard error; in your original example, `a` is completely invisible to `bar`.  (Note that if you had redeclared it with a different type, that would also make the program's meaning undefined.)

Comment: Thank you, gcc's diagnostic messages seem more clear to me.

Comment: A test at godbolt.com gives different messages depending on whether `b` is declared in `foo` or not. I suspect the particular cause of the message OP sees is that a function identifier always refers to the same function in a module, so the `b` in `bar` **must** refer to the same `b` as in `foo`, but its declaration is out of scope, whereas `a` could refer to a different object.